React-Native: SafeAreaView not working in Modal
Following is done for a mobile app on android in react native.
I want to display a text in the center of the screen, however even with a SafeAreaView it is not in the center, it is still a bit off, this means that the red background goes beyond the screen. How can I fix this?

import { Image, Modal, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";


function ImageSolver({ image, open, onClose }) {
  return (
        <Modal visible={open} animationType={"slide"} onRequestClose={onClose}>
            <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 bg-cloud p-4">
                <View className="flex mb-4">
                    <TouchableOpacity className="self-start" activeOpacity={0.6}>
                        <Image 
                            source={icons.chevronLeft}
                            className="w-6 h-6"
                            resizeMode="contain"
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View className="flex justify-center relative bg-slate-300 rounded-2xl">
                    <Image 
                        source={{ uri: image }}
                        className="h-28 rounded-2xl"
                        resizeMode="contain"
                    />
                </View>

                    <View className="flex justify-end items-center h-full bg-red-300">
                        <Flow size={40} color="#222" />
                        <Text className="font-medium">Solving Problem...</Text>
                    </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </Modal>
    );
}


I also tried the SafeAreaViewProvider, still does not work

For some reason wrapping the SafeAreaView to the SafeAreaProvider worked for me
